Login failure from ASP.NET page using PrincipalContext
Have been researching this and could not find a solution. We are using LDAP authentication in an ASP.NET webforms app. Overall it is working fine, but for a group of users, the login fails, verified the username and password is correct.
I used the UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity and was able to find the user. What might be the possible issue? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Searched all over the site and other sites, see different explanations, but could not find a solution
